# What's that movie where the character travels back in time by his mind?

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

I watched a movie back when I was a kid, I would say during the 80's maybe early 90's.
This movie was about a character who succeeded in time traveling by just thinking of it. At the end of the movie, he finds a contemporary money coin and suddenly he realises he's not from that old time and he gets back in the future.

I cannot remember the title.

Any ideas? ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Somewhere in Time (1980)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somewhere_in_Time_(film)) seems to be what you're looking for.

Apparently the time travel was some form of self-hypnosis, which explains why seeing the coin pulled him out of his trance.

Answer (score 13):

It could be [Somewhere In Time](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081534/combined).

Christopher Reeve plays the part of a young playwright who is given a pocket watch by an older woman at the performance of his first play. He later sees a picture of the same woman when she was a young actress. Entranced by her beauty, he uses hypnosis to travel back to 1912 to see her again. Then, just after they declare their love for each other, the coin shows up, throwing him back into his own time.